# Python script to convert selected object to collection instance

Tags: python, scripting

New to Python, got as far as creating a collection with the same name as the selected object, now I just need to create a collection instance from it.

```
import bpy

selection_names = bpy.context.selected_objects
for i in selection_names:
     print(i.name)
bpy.ops.object.move_to_collection(collection_index=0, is_new=True, new_collection_name=i.name)
```

Comment: I believe [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIg-KOeFxkg&list=PL1fkRtMmJ4OOrY20bOVlxn_PFYx9ly97j&index=10) scripting for artists video fully covers what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you want is [`bpy.ops.object.collection_instance_add`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.collection_instance_add).  If, for example you had a collection called "monkeys", you could add it using this command:

```py
bpy.ops.object.collection_instance_add(collection='monkeys', align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
```

All of the arguments except the first are optional.

Comment: Worked. Now I just need to create a mini addon, so that it can be assigned a shortcut to.

Comment: Managed to add shortcut with [this addon](https://github.com/snuq/Script-Shortcut).

Comment: @JohnNope Good job with the other addon.